# Arguments not passed to function in c Kernel

Tags: c, function, operating-system, arguments, kernel

I'm currently working on a home-made OS project. I've succesfully written a bootloader which switches the computer into protected mode and loads the kernel, which is written in c. My kernel loads fine, but I have a problem calling functions outside of main(). The function seems to execute fine, but from what I can tell none of the arguments are being passed. I can't figure out why this is, and hope someone here can tell me what my problem is. Below is the code to my kernel, as well as the commands used to compiler it.

EDIT:
After rereading my question I think I need to clarify what I mean when I say that arguments are not being passed. When I call print_char, no matter what values I pass as arguments it has no effect. However, if I modify the variables inside of the function it works fine.

kernel.c

```
#define VIDEO_ADDRESS 0xb8000
#define WHITE_BLACK 0x0f

void print_char(char character, int col, int row, char att_byte) {
    unsigned char* vid_mem = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_ADDRESS;
    int offset;

    if (!att_byte) {
        att_byte = WHITE_BLACK;
    }

    offset += 2*col;
    offset += 80*row;

    vid_mem[offset] = character;
    vid_mem[offset+1] = att_byte;
}

void start() {
    clear_screen();
    print_char('X', 0, 0, WHITE_BLACK);
}
```

build.bat

```
nasm boot.asm -f bin -o boot.bin
nasm kernel_entry.asm -f elf -o kernel_entry.o
gcc -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o

ld -T NUL -o kernel.tmp -Ttext 0x1000 kernel_entry.o kernel.o

objcopy -O binary -j .text kernel.tmp kernel.bin 

type boot.bin kernel.bin > OS.bin

qemu-system-i386 OS.bin
```

Comment: Please post the output of your `build.bat` script

Comment: What is the value of `WHITE_BLACK` macro? Why you tell that no arguments seams to be passed?

Comment: Maybe the output of `build.bat` already tell to you that `offset` was uninitialized.

Comment: Every command completes successfully without any errors or warnings.
WHITE_BLACK is defined at the top of kernel.c

Comment: take a look to  Basile Starynkevitch's comment on the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research and messing around with `gcc` and `ld` for a few hours, I've solved my problem.

I build `kernel.c` using the following commands:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors -nostdlib kernel.c -o kernel.exe

ld -nostdlib -Ttext 0x1000 -o kernel.tmp kernel_entry.o kernel.exe
objcopy -O binary -j .text  kernel.tmp kernel.bin
```

I am not entirely sure why this works and my previous attempts didn't, but for now everything is working as it should. Thanks for all the help I received.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't initialize your variable:

```
int offset = 0;
```

Notice that the first use of offset was this:

```
offset += 2*col;
```

which means that either you should have initialized `offset` to 0, or you should change that line to this:

```
offset = 2*col;
```

Comment: You should have compiled with `gcc -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -c -O1 kernel.c` and you would have been warned by `gcc`

Comment: the variable offset is defined at the begginning of print_char(), though I don't immediately assign a value to it.
@Basile Starynkevitch I tried compiling with your suggestion, and I did get warned by gcc. Thanksm but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: It might not solve all of your problems but it should at least fix one problem.  You need to initialize `offset` to 0 because the first thing you do to it is `offset += 2*col` which means you are using an uninitialized value.  `offset` could be anything at that point but probably not what you expected.